# Simplest way to determine return type of function

Tags: c++, function, c++17, return-type, compile-time

Given a very simple, but lengthy function, such as:

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    return 1;
}

// using ReturnTypeOfFoo = ???
```

What is the most simple and concise way to determine the function's return type (`ReturnTypeOfFoo`, in this example: `int`) at compile time *without repeating the function's parameter types* (by name only, since it is known that the function does not have any additional overloads)?

Comment: Depending on the compiler or the support libraries available to you... 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/attributes?view=vs-2017, Fairly sure that Concepts also has some APIs which allow you to deduce this information at run time or compile time.

Comment: Maybe `decltype(foo)::result_type`?

Comment: maybe https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of?

Comment: @ThomasLang where does this come from? `decltype(foo)` is a function that has no `result_type` member, or do I miss something?

Comment: @user463035818 You may be right here, I was referring to the `result_type` member of a `std::function` type.

Comment: @ThomasLang actually thats a nice idea. Unfortunately you need to know the return type before you can create a `std::function` from a plain function ;).  Maybe with deduction guides something along the line of `decltype( std::function(&foo))::result_type` can be made to work

Comment: @ThomasLange yes it can :) see NathanOlivers answer

Comment: @user463035818 - exactly: through deduction guides (only from C++17)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can leverage [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) here which will give you an alias for the functions return type.  This does require C++17 support, since it relies on [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), but it will work with any callable type:

```
using ReturnTypeOfFoo = decltype(std::function{foo})::result_type;
```

---

We can make this a little more generic like

```
template<typename Callable>
using return_type_of_t = 
    typename decltype(std::function{std::declval<Callable>()})::result_type;
```

which then lets you use it like

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    return 1;
}

auto bar = [](){ return 1; };

struct baz_ 
{ 
    double operator()(){ return 0; } 
} baz;

using ReturnTypeOfFoo = return_type_of_t<decltype(foo)>;
using ReturnTypeOfBar = return_type_of_t<decltype(bar)>;
using ReturnTypeOfBaz = return_type_of_t<decltype(baz)>;
```

---

This technique only works if the function is not overloaded or the function do not have multiple `operator()`'s defined.

Comment: Very compact! I can confirm the one-liner also works for template methods, as long as all template arguments specified.

Comment: In C++17:  `using ReturnType = std::invoke_result_t<decltype(foo)>;`

Comment: only if the `foo` (and it's `operator()`) is not ambiguous.

Comment: fwiw, I comes from [you comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75686321/deducing-return-type-of-a-capturing-lambda-function-operator-without-an-inst#comment133523308_75686321)

Comment: @appleapple That is limitation of any technique to try and do this automagically.

Comment: @NathanOliver not if you know the parameter, as at the link.

Comment: @appleapple Sure, but then then you have to know things and provide those things.  If you want to do it without knowing then you can't have an ambiguity.

Comment: @NathanOliver true, just point out the limitation.

Comment: @NathanOliver I mean "I just point out the limitation here", not asking you to edit, just in case.

Answer (score 27):

Most simple and concise is probably:

```
template <typename R, typename... Args>
R return_type_of(R(*)(Args...));

using ReturnTypeOfFoo = decltype(return_type_of(foo));
```

Note that this won't work for function objects or pointers to member functions. Just functions, that aren't overloaded or templates, or `noexcept`.

But this can be extended to support all of those cases, if so desired, by adding more overloads of `return_type_of`.

Answer (score 19):

I don't know if is the simplest way (if you can use C++17 surely isn't: see NathanOliver's answer) but... what about declaring a function as follows:

```
template <typename R, typename ... Args>
R getRetType (R(*)(Args...));
```

and using `decltype()`?

```
using ReturnTypeOfFoo = decltype( getRetType(&foo) );
```

Observe that `getRetType()` is only declared and not defined because is called only a `decltype()`, so only the returned type is relevant.

Answer (score -1):

Years later but you may be interested in my own (free) solution [here](https://github.com/HexadigmSystems/FunctionTraits) (production grade, fully documented). It's a full implementation of some of the other ideas you've seen here (see responses by Barry and max66). You can target almost anything about a function however (within the limitations of C++ itself), not just the return type.

Download the code, add "TypeTraits.h" and "CompilerVersions.h" to your project, then do the following (note that you don't have to explicitly #include "CompilerVersions.h", it's automatically #included in "TypeTraits.h")

```
#include "TypeTraits.h"
using namespace StdExt; // Everything's in this namespace
using ReturnTypeOfFoo = ReturnType_t<decltype(foo)>;
```