# Split function signature of lambda in pattern match of specialization in c++-17

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-specialization

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                         
#include <string>                                                                                                                           
#include <array>                                                                                                                            
#include <map>                                                                                                                              
#include <functional>                                                                                                                       

template<typename T> struct tag {};                                                                                                         

template <typename LambdaType, typename=void>                                                                                               
struct split {                                                                                                                              
    split(LambdaType &&f) {                                                                                                                 
        std::cout << "[]()" << std::endl;                                                                                                   
    }                                                                                                                                       
};                                                                                                                                          

template <typename RetType, typename... ArgTypes>                                                                                           
struct split<std::function<RetType(ArgTypes...)>>  {                                                                                        
    split(std::function<RetType(ArgTypes...)> &&f) {                                                                                        
        std::cout << "std::function" << std::endl;                                                                                          
    };                                                                                                                                      
};                                                                                                                                          

template <typename RetType, typename... ArgTypes>                                                                                           
struct split<RetType(*)(ArgTypes...)> {                                                                                                     
    split(RetType(*f)(ArgTypes...)) {                                                                                                       
        std::cout << "func-ptr" << std::endl;                                                                                               
    };                                                                                                                                      
};                                                                                                                                          

void f1(int) {};                                                                                                                            

int                                                                                                                                         
main(int argc, char **argv) {                                                                                                               

    new split<std::decay<decltype(f1)>::type>(f1);                                                                                          
    new split<std::function<void(int)>>(std::function<void(int)>([](int) {}));                                                              

    /* how can I extract the argument type template pack from lambda ? */                                                                   
    new split([](int){});                                                                                                                   
    return 0;                                                                                                                               
}
```

There are 2 specializations for `split`, one for `std::function<RetType(ArgTypes...)>` and one for `RetType(*)(ArgTypes...)` . For both specialization I get the `RetType` and `ArgTypes...` template argument and pack by pattern matching. However I wonder weather there is some way to do the same with a `lambda` as argument?

How can I extract `RetType` and `ArgTypes...` of a lambda in a specialization for the `new split([](int){})` line ?

Comment: You can get the return type using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53673648/4342498).  I'm not sure if you can get the argument type(s)

Comment: You can try SFINAE on is_convertible to `RetType(*)(ArgTypes...)`. Would that work for you? That way you'll handle captureless lambdas too.

Comment: @Barry Duplicate is about deducing the return type of a function while this question is about deducing both the return type and argument types of a lambda (closure) type.

Comment: @Barry (I did not want reopen alone without discussion, I wanted to vote... but I forgot that dupe-hammer comes with reopen-hammer.)

Comment: @Holt Heh, I know right - the problems of the hammer... But anyway, I think that answer does answer this question. And for what it's worth - the part of that answer that doesn't answer this question isn't included in your answer either, right?

Comment: @Barry Only the first answer of the dupe apply, and even in this case, it's mostly targeted at the return type. However, I agree that my answer is not that better, but SergyA's one may add something. If OP's find the dupe sufficient, then let's dupe-hammer it.

Comment: @KonradEisele Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53673442/simplest-way-to-determine-return-type-of-function?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer your question? If not, could you clarify how you want to use the return type / argument types so that we can expand the answers here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use template class argument deduction with `std::function`:

```
template <typename LambdaType, typename=void>                                                                                               
struct split {                                                                                                                              
    using StdFunctionType = decltype(std::function{std::declval<LambdaType>()});                                                                                                                                  
};
```

Once you have the `std::function` corresponding to your lambda, you can retrieve the return and argument types using template specialization.

This works because `std::function` has a [deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/deduction_guides):

```
template<class F>
function(F) -> function</*see below*/>;
```

> If `decltype(&F::operator())` is of the form `R(G::*)(A...)` (optionally `cv`-qualified, optionally `noexcept`, optionally lvalue reference qualified) for some class type `G`, then the deduced type is `std::function<R(A...)>`. This overload only participates in overload resolution if `&F::operator()` is well-formed when treated as an unevaluated operand.

Answer (score 2):

You can go through some sort of trickery, for example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename LambdaType, typename=void>                                                                                               
struct split {                                                                                                                              
    split(LambdaType &&f) { deduce(&LambdaType::operator()); }
    template<class RET, class CLOSURE, class... ARGS>
    void deduce(RET(CLOSURE::*)(ARGS...) const) {
       // You have your return and args here
    }
};                                                                                                                                          


template <typename RetType, typename... ArgTypes>                                                                                           
struct split<RetType(*)(ArgTypes...)> {                                                                                                     
    split(RetType(*f)(ArgTypes...));                                                                                                                                      
};                                                                                                                                  

void f1(int) {};                                                                                                                            

int                                                                                                                                         
main(int argc, char **argv) {                                                                                                               

    split<std::decay_t<decltype(f1)>>{f1};                                                                                          

    /* how can I extract the argument type template pack from lambda ? */                                                                   
    split([](int){});                                                                                                                   
    return 0;                                                                                                                               
}
```

Comment: Tiny (soooo tiny) caveat, this does not (directly) work with `mutable` lambda due to the `const`-qualification of the call-operator in `deduce()`.

Comment: Question: Is there a type_trait predicate to test weather a type is a lambda?

Comment: I added ont method I found as an answer below. I use subclassing of the specialization case for lambdas operator()...Its a bit like your method but using subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

I found one method that uses subclassing the specialization (seen [here](https://qiita.com/angeart/items/94734d68999eca575881)):

```
/* g++ -std=c++17 */
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

template<typename T> struct tag {};
struct mybase {};

/* subclass specialization on type of operator() of lambda: */
template<class Ld>
struct split : split<decltype(&Ld::operator())>
{
    split(Ld &&f) : split<decltype(&Ld::operator())>(std::forward<Ld>(f)) {};
};

template <typename RetType, typename... ArgTypes>
struct split<std::function<RetType(ArgTypes...)>>  {
    split(std::function<RetType(ArgTypes...)> &&f) {
        std::cout << "std::function" << std::endl;
    };
};

template <typename RetType, typename... ArgTypes>
struct split<RetType(*)(ArgTypes...)> {
    split(RetType(*f)(ArgTypes...)) {
        std::cout << "func-ptr" << std::endl;
    };
};

template <typename RetType, class Cls, typename... ArgTypes>
struct split<RetType(Cls::*)(ArgTypes...) const >  {
    split(const Cls &&f) {
        std::cout << "[]() const" << std::endl;
    };
};

template <typename RetType, class Cls, typename... ArgTypes>
struct split<RetType(Cls::*)(ArgTypes...) >  {
    split(Cls &&f) {
        std::cout << "[]()" << std::endl;
    };
};


void f1(int) {};

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {

    new split<std::decay<decltype(f1)>::type>(f1);
    new split<std::function<void(int)>>(std::function<void(int)>([](int) {}));

    /* no g++-17: */
    //auto l = [](int){};
    //new split<decltype(l)>(std::forward<decltype(l)>(l));

    /* g++-17: */
    new split([](int){});

    return 0;
}
```