# Get return type of lambda expression

Tags: c++, lambda, generic-programming, return-type, template-argument-deduction

I am developing a C++ iterator that evaluates a lambda expression each time the iterator is dereferenced.

So I implemented a custom iterator class, and I overloaded the dereference operator, in a way it executes the lambda expression on each dereference, this way I can put the expression I need in the lambda function.

Everything works fine, but it is not type-generic, because at line 9 in the code below I'm assuming the lambda expression will return a double. How do I get the return type of the Lambda? I tried `std::result_of<Lambda>`, but it didn't work.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <cmath>

template <class Iterator, class Lambda>
struct LambdaIterator: Iterator {
public:
    using value_type = double; // <--- How do I get the return type of the lambda?

    LambdaIterator(Iterator&& begin, Lambda&& lambda) :
        Iterator(std::forward<Iterator>(begin)),
        lamdaexpr(std::forward<Lambda>(lambda)) {}

    value_type operator*() {
        return lamdaexpr(*static_cast<Iterator&>(*this));
    }
private:
    Lambda lamdaexpr;
};

// Helper function, only needed to easily instantiate the iterator
template <class Iterator, class Lambda>
LambdaIterator<Iterator, Lambda> MakeLambdaIterator(Iterator&& begin, Lambda&& lambda) {
    return {std::forward<Iterator>(begin), std::forward<Lambda>(lambda)};
}

template<class BeginIterator, class EndIterator>
typename BeginIterator::value_type Sum(BeginIterator begin, EndIterator end) {
    typename BeginIterator::value_type sum = 0;

    while (begin != end) {
        sum += *begin;
        begin++;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<double> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        vec.push_back(i); // Puts some data into the vector

    std::cout << Sum(vec.begin(), vec.end()) << std::endl; // Works fine
    std::cout << Sum(MakeLambdaIterator(vec.begin(),
                     [](double item) -> double { // Works as long as it returns a double
                        return sqrt(item); // Prints the sum of the square roots
                     } ), vec.end()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << Sum(MakeLambdaIterator(vec.begin(),
                     [](double item) -> double {
                        return pow(item, 2); // Prints the sum of the squares
                     } ), vec.end()) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53673442/simplest-way-to-determine-return-type-of-function.  The Q is about functions but the accepted answer works for all callables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I get the return type of the Lambda?

Taking in count that you know the type of the argument, it seems to me that your looking for an execution inside `decltype()`.

I mean something as

```
using value_type = decltype( std::declval<Lambda>()(*std::declval<Iterator>()) );
```

This works also with a generic-lambda.

Off topic: if you want to use forward semantics for `LambdaIterator()` constructor, you have to transform it in a template one to have `&&` as universal reference instead of r-value reference.

I mean: you should write is as follows

```
  template <typename I, typename L>
  LambdaIterator (I && begin, L && lambda)
     : Iterator{std::forward<I>(begin)}, lamdaexpr{std::forward<L>(lambda)}
     { }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways how you can achieve it, the easiest seem to be following:

```
decltype(auto) operator*() {
    return lamdaexpr(*static_cast<Iterator&>(*this));
}
```