# How to get the return type of a function with std::result_of?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, return-type, type-traits

I have a function quite complex

```
template<class E>
auto foo(E&& e);
```

And I want to get the return type by using

```
template<class E> using Foo = decltype(foo(E{}));
```

This cannot compile for E&& not okay.

I try using `std::result_of` many ways, but still failed. Any way to get the returned type?

---

**Edit**

The `foo` is

```
 template<class E>
 auto xt::strided_view(
     E &&e, 
     const xstrided_slice_vector &slices
 )
```

https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/xstrided_view.html#namespacext_1aca6714111810062b91a1c9e31bd69b26

tried the following, does not work

```
    using E = xtensor<int, 2>;
    using SV = xt::xstrided_slice_vector;

    static_assert(is_same<
        invoke_result_t<decltype(xt::strided_view<E>), E, SV>,
        decltype(v)
    >::value);

    static_assert(is_same<
        decltype(xt::strided_view(declval<E>(), sv)),
        decltype(v)
    >::value);
```

showing

```
error C3556: 'xt::strided_view': incorrect argument to 'decltype'
 error C2955: 'std::is_same': use of class template requires template argument list
```

Comment: Alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53673648/4342498

Comment: `decltype(foo(std::declval<E>()))`?

Comment: "*This cannot compile for E&& not okay.*" Why not? Is `E` not default-constructible?

Comment: @Justin tried, doesn't work.

Comment: `template<class E> auto xt::strided_view( E &&e, const xstrided_slice_vector &slices)` is not a valid complete function declaration, as it's lacking a return type.

Comment: In the updated `foo` you should use `std::invoke_result_t<decltype(xt::strided_view<E>), E, xstrided_slice_vector>;`: Here is an example: https://godbolt.org/z/7d9ojv

Comment: @JeJo Tried, but not work.

Answer (score 2):

> Any way to get the returned type?

You have either of the followings:

1. using [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)

   ```
   template<class E> using Foo = decltype(foo(std::declval<E>()));
   ```
2. using [`std::invoke_result_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) (since [c+++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%2b17))

   ```
   template<class E> using Foo = std::invoke_result_t<decltype(foo<E>), E>;
   ```
3. using [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)

   ```
   template<class E> using Foo = decltype(foo<E>(E{}));
   ```

In which, the last one is really not recommended as `E` should be default constructed in the function call(i.e. `foo<E>(E{})`).

---

> I tried using `std::result_of` many ways, but still failed.

Note that, [`std::result_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) is deprecated in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) and (will be or already) removed from the standard in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20). Hence, trying to build something which standard does not support, is not a good idea (when you upgrade to newer standards in the future).