# deduce return type of lambda with arguments

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

Is it possible to deduce the return type of a lambda function without providing the types of arguments (C++14)?
Assume that the return type does not depend on the arguments
(i.e. excluding cases such as `f_auto()`).

So far, I have tried to deduce the return type given the types of arguments.

```cpp
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <utility>

// Deduces the return type of Func() called with Args, void if invalid.
// Case of no arguments.
template <class Func, class... Args>
class ResultOf {
 private:
  template <class>
  static void Eval(...);
  template <class U>
  static auto Eval(decltype(std::declval<U>()())* r) {
    return *r;
  }

 public:
  using type = decltype(Eval<Func>(0));
};

// Case of one or more arguments.
template <class Func, class T, class... TT>
struct ResultOf<Func, T, TT...> {
 private:
  template <class...>
  static void Eval(...);
  template <class U, class... UU>
  static auto Eval(decltype(std::declval<Func>()( //
      std::declval<U>(), std::declval<UU>()...))* r) {
    return *r;
  }

 public:
  using type = decltype(Eval<T, TT...>(0));
};

template <class... Args, class Func>
std::string GetReturnType(Func func) {
  using type = typename ResultOf<Func, Args...>::type;
  return typeid(type).name();
}

#define P(func, ...)                                                 \
  do {                                                               \
    std::cout << (#func) << '(' << (#__VA_ARGS__) << ')' << "  ->  " \
              << GetReturnType<__VA_ARGS__>(func) << std::endl;      \
  } while (0)

int main() {
  auto f_void = []() { return 0; };
  auto f_int = [](int a) { return a; };
  auto f_int_double = [](int a, double b) { return a + b; };
  auto f_auto = [](auto a) { return a; };

  P(f_void);
  P(f_int, int);
  P(f_int, double);
  P(f_int_double, int, double);
  P(f_int_double, int, int);
  P(f_auto, int);
  P(f_auto, double);
}
```

Output

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 main.cpp -o main
$ ./main | c++filt -t
f_void()  ->  int
f_int(int)  ->  int
f_int(double)  ->  int
f_int_double(int, double)  ->  double
f_int_double(int, int)  ->  double
f_auto(int)  ->  int
f_auto(double)  ->  double
```

Update: Solution based on the answer by @igortandetnik

```cpp
// Deduces the return type of `Func::operator() const` if unambiguous.
template <class Func>
class ResultOfDeducedArgs {
 private:
  template <class...>
  static void Eval(...);
  template <class R, class... Args>
  static R Ret(R (Func::*)(Args...) const);
  template <class T>
  static auto Eval(decltype(Ret(&T::operator()))* r) {
    return *r;
  }

 public:
  using type = decltype(Eval<Func>(0));
};
```

Output

```
f_int()  ->  int
f_int_double()  ->  double
f_auto()  ->  void
```

Comment: `f_auto`  is the polymorphic identity function, and could be called `f_ident`; BTW, what about  the type of `f_auto(f_auto)` ? See also [type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) wikipage

Comment: What are you using this for? Surely just explicitly writing out the return type should just work....

Comment: [`using type = typename decltype(std::function{func})::result_type;`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53673648).

Comment: @Evg this requires C++17

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso I need to pass this lambda to a template function and its logic depends on the return type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are willing to limit yourself to non-generic lambdas (and in general to class objects with exactly one `operator()` overload), then something like this should work (not tested):

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
R ResultOf(R (T::*)(Args...));
```

Used as

```
using R = decltype(ResultOf(&decltype(my_lambda)::operator()));
```

This could be wrapped in helper classes for nicer syntax; we leave this as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: It should be `R ResultOf(R (T::*)(Args...) const);` to work with non-`mutable` lambdas.

Comment: @igortandetnik, @Evg
this works, thanks;
needed `R ResultOf(R (T::*)(Args...) const);`; added to the original question