# How to check whether a function pointer returns bool

Tags: c++, templates, std-function

I have a template class that takes a std::function as parameter.

Within the class I need a member function returning bool.

If the cbFunctionT returns bool, the function should return that.
If the cbFunctionT returns anything other (or is void), the function should return false.

Expect that I need to use the std::enable_if for that.

Question is how can I check whether cbFunctionT returns bool.
In the code below I used the std::is_same as a placeholder for the one I am looking for.

```
template<typename cbFunctionT> 
class CallBack
{
    template<typename T = cbFunctionT
        typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T,bool>::value>* = nullptr>
    bool funct()
    {
        return cbFunctionT();
    }
    
    template<typename T = cbFunctionT>
    bool funct()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps specialize the entire template for `std::function<bool (Args...)>`?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53673442/simplest-way-to-determine-return-type-of-function

Comment: Do you mean **exactly** `bool`? Is `const bool` acceptable ? `bool&` ? Something that's implicitly or explicitly convertible to `bool` ?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to say you'd like to call an `std::function` member of type `cbFunctionT`, possibly called `cbFunction`? This code looks like it would return `false` every time because it tests that `cbFunctionT` is `bool` and `bool()` is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's sufficient to write

```
template<typename T = cbFunctionT>
bool funct()
{
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<decltype(T()), bool>)
      return T();
    else
      return false;
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't need to be template function to compile. `std::enable_if` needed that in the OP's example to do specialization, but `if constexpr` can work using `cbFunctionT` in place of `T`.

Comment: @parktomatomi: The `if constexpr` is C++17 to make the code much less verbose, but the key part of the answer is `decltype(T())`. That would work in a `std::enable_if` as well.

Answer (score 0):

My answer takes the liberty of assuming `funct` is meant to invoke a data member of type `cbFunctionT`, rather than construct the type itself.

MSalters' *general* answer (to use `if constexpr`) is the correct answer if you're able to use C++17 or later. The compiler will evaluate the condition at compile-time and only compile the content inside the selected branch. This enables you to do things inline that you previously had to use `std::enable_if` for.

But if you're using C++11 or C++14, you can still pull that `enable_if` out of your class with a generalized helper:

```cpp
template <bool condition, typename FTrue, typename FFalse, typename... Ts, typename std::enable_if<condition, int>::type = 0>
auto IfConst(FTrue ftrue, FFalse ffalse, Ts&&... ts) -> decltype(ftrue(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)) {
    return ftrue(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}

template <bool condition, typename FTrue, typename FFalse, typename... Ts, typename std::enable_if<!condition, int>::type = 0>
auto IfConst(FTrue, FFalse ffalse, Ts&&... ts) -> decltype(ffalse(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)) {
    return ffalse(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}
```

Then you can implement your goal in a non-template method:

```cpp
template<typename cbFunctionT> 
class CallBack
{
    cbFunctionT cbFunction;
public:
    CallBack(cbFunctionT cbFunction) : cbFunction(cbFunction) {}
    bool funct() { 
        return IfConst<std::is_same<cbFunctionT, std::function<bool()>>::value>(
            [this]() { return cbFunction && cbFunction(); },
            []() { return false; });
    }
};
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/o544WM