# C++ 17: Using alias template bug in gcc?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer

Snippet:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct CallableTrait;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct CallableTrait<std::function<R(Args...)>>
{
    using ReturnType = R;
};

template <typename Callable>
using CallableTraitT = CallableTrait<decltype(std::function{std::declval<Callable>()})>;

template <typename Callable>
auto test(Callable&&)
{
    using CallableInfo = CallableTraitT<Callable>;
    static_assert(!std::is_void_v<typename CallableInfo::ReturnType>);
}

int main()
{
    test([]() { return 42; });
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/avGv3n)

This compiles fine with `clang-12.0.0` and `MSVC-19.16.27034`, but `gcc-11.0.0` throws an error:

```
prog.cc: In instantiation of 'auto test(Callable&&) [with Callable = main()::<lambda()>]':
prog.cc:25:29:   required from here
prog.cc:20:25: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct CallableTrait<main()::<lambda()> >'
   20 |     static_assert(!std::is_void_v<typename CallableInfo::ReturnType>);
      |                    ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:5:8: note: declaration of 'struct CallableTrait<main()::<lambda()> >'
    5 | struct CallableTrait;
      |
```

Who is right and who isn't?

**EDIT:**
Bug is tracked here [gcc-bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=98077)

Comment: `[]() { return 42; }` ≠ `std::function<int()>`.

Comment: What you want is basically what I do here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53673648/4342498

Comment: @NathanOliver: Thx, but the question was why 2 of 3 compilers are good, while gcc thinks this is wrong.

Comment: @Eljay: but `CallableTraitT` "calls" `std::function`...

Comment: And indeed, adding `std::function` makes gcc happy [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YY8G5c).

Comment: Seems really a gcc bug, "inlining" the traits solves the issue [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E1KoKE).

Comment: @Jarod42: Yes, I had to inline it too. Will for now make an ifdef for the three compilers.

Comment: Definitely a gcc bug with how CTAD is done: https://godbolt.org/z/qc77oK

Comment: @Artyer: I don't see double CTAD here, there is only the one from `std::function`

Comment: @Jarod42 As in the commented out line (CTAD is done once in the function, and once in  `CallableTraitT` which uses `CallableTrait`). That was just something I found while making the minimum example (as seen here: https://godbolt.org/z/8fh6sz it names the type `main()::<lambda()>::._anon_0`, where `._anon_0` is some mysterious internal name which I can't find any reference/documentation on. Obviously a compiler error at this point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is tracked here [gcc-bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=98077)

Comment: I don't think so. Jonathan just reduced the example, it's not been officially Confirmed yet.

Comment: @cigien: my bad. I am not aware of the semantics in bugzilla. Will make a defensive edit.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for filing the bug report. It *does* look like a bug to me, for what that's worth :)