# Take generic lambda return type into consideration for SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, sfinae

I'd like to have a function that takes a generic lambda, but I need slightly different logic based on the lambda's return type. For example, I'd like to do something like the following (this is a contrived example):

```cpp
template<typename F>
void foo(F &&function) {
    auto result = function();
    // Have different behavior based on `result`'s type.
}
```

To facilitate this, I thought I could use SFINAE. In my mind, this would look something like:

```cpp
template<typename F,
         typename std::enable_if_t<???>>
void foo(F &&function) {

}
```

Does anyone know how I can enable/disable a method based on the return type of `F`?

Comment: How about just calling `bar(result)` with `bar()` having a bunch of overloads? like https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bWGqfGada

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53673442/simplest-way-to-determine-return-type-of-function

Comment: @NathanOliver It's related, but not a dupe. OP wants to know how to do different things based on the return type, not how to actually get at that type (though that's necessary, of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need SFINAE for this. As mentioned in a comment, you could just write the different logic based on the return type in different overloads, and call that overload set

```
void f(int); // do the logic for an int
void f(double); // do the logic for a double
// ... and so on

template<typename F>
void foo(F &&function) 
{
    auto result = function();
    f(result); // get different behavior based on `result`'s type.
}
```

If the logic needs some data other than the return value, you'll need to pass that to the helper `f`.

---

To avoid that, and have all the logic in one place, you could write a compile time "switch" on the type of the return value

```
template<typename F>
void foo(F &&function) 
{
    auto result = function();
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(result), int>)
      // logic for an int
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(result), double>)
      // logic for a double
    else
      // ... and so on
}
```

---

Note that these two options are not *exactly* equivalent, i.e. overload resolution may not behave exactly the same as `is_same` in all cases, due to factors like implicit conversions, etc. so you have to be a bit careful there. One fix would be to write an overload for the first version that catches everything other than exact conversions

```
template<typename T>
void f(T) = delete;
```

and this will be much closer to the second version.

Comment: Nitpick: The two are not "quite" equivalent, especially for types like `int` and `double`, because of dastardly implicit conversions which might or might not be desirable.

Comment: @Frank Good point, I've added a small caveat at the end. I don't want to get into *too* much detail here, but this should suffice.