# Deducing return type of a capturing lambda function `operator()` without an instantiated lambda variable

Tags: c++, c++23

What I'm trying to do is to deduce return type of a capturing lambda from inside the class where the lambda is executed (never stored) so that the return type is not required to be part of class signature.

Since lambda is capturing the default constructor is deleted so I wrote such code:

```
using AppliedReturnType =
decltype
(
  std::apply
  (
    []( auto& ...items )
    {
      std::optional< ApplyLambda > lambda; // optional used here to work around construction

      return lambda.value()( items... ); // value used without initialization
    },
    t_
  )
);
```

Am I correct in assumption that since I'm using this code only in decltype evaluation I'd say that such code is not a problem no matter the std::optional implementation/UB at runtime?

And out of curiosity, is there a better way to do something like this? (not having the type in class template list is a must)

EDIT: editing simplified implementation a bit (based on the answers) so that it won't hurt so much the eyes of other readers that would copy paste code from such a question...

Below is a simplified implementation (extremely dumbed down as I'm certain that nobody would bother with 300+ lines of code...):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <tuple>

template< typename Callable, typename Tuple >
class C
{
public:
  C( Callable&& callable, Tuple&& t )
    : t_{ std::move( t ) }
    , result_
      {
          std::apply
          (
            callable,
            t_
          )
      }
  {}
  
  auto result() const { return result_; }

private:
  Tuple t_;

  using AppliedReturnType =
    decltype
    (
      std::apply
      (
        []( auto& ...items )
        {
          std::optional< Callable > callable;

          return callable.value()( items... );
        },
        t_
      )
    );
    
  AppliedReturnType result_;
};

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    
    auto lambda = [&i]( auto&... items ) { return ( items + ...) + i; };
    
    C c{ std::move( lambda ), std::tuple{ 1, 2, 3 } };
    
    std::cout << c.result() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: You can use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53673648/4342498) to get the return type of any callable.

Comment: There is `std::declval` to get type in unevaluated context.

Comment: I see no reason why you're doing apply twice (`std::apply` and the lambda you have (which is a worse version of `std::invoke`)).

Comment: @NathanOliver only when it doesn't have ambiguous `operator()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that since everything is in `decltype`, there is no issue, although you can simplify that stuff with

```
using AppliedReturnType = decltype(std::apply(std::declval<ApplyLambda>(), t_));
```

---

And as pointed out in the comments, you do not need that inner lambda in your constructor either

```
C( ApplyLambda& lambda, Tuple&& t )
    : t_{ std::move( t ) }
    , result_{ std::apply( lambda, t_ ) }
  {}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4qsGqY1oW)

Answer (score 2):

I have a bunch of comments here:

---

```cpp
template< typename ApplyLambda, typename Tuple >
```

Don't name template parameters `Lambda` - there's no reason to ever *require* a lambda, any callable is fine. So just `F`, or `ApplyF`, or `Callable`, or something.

The same thing applies to the name of the variable.

---

This:

```cpp
            [&lambda]( auto& ...items )
            {
              return lambda( items... );
            },
```

This is a very long, and incorrect, way of writing just `lambda`. It works here because you're passing the tuple as an lvalue, but if you forwarded it, then the elements of the tuple would be moved, and `auto&...` wouldn't compile.

Also if the callable returned a reference type (e.g. `int&`), you're dropping that on the floor, this spelling returns `int`.

Just: `lambda`.

---

Likewise this:

```cpp
  using AppliedReturnType =
    decltype
    (
      std::apply
      (
        []( auto& ...items )
        {
          std::optional< ApplyLambda > lambda;

          return lambda.value()( items... );
        },
        t_
      )
    );
```

as above, the lambda passed in here could just be `lambda`, but you don't have an object of that type yet - so you can make one using `declval`:

```cpp
  using AppliedReturnType = decltype(std::apply(std::declval<F&>(), std::declval<Tuple&>());
```

Note the `&` because you're passing it as an lvalue.

---

Here:

```cpp
  C( ApplyLambda& lambda, Tuple&& t )
```

Don't take callables by lvalue references - since it (ironically) prohibits passing in lambdas.

---

Putting it all together:

```cpp
template <typename F, typename Tuple>
class C
{
  using R = decltype(std::apply(std::declval<F&>(), std::declval<Tuple&>()));
public:
  Tuple t_;
  R result_;

public:
  C( F f, Tuple&& t )
    : t_{ std::move( t ) }
    , result_{std::apply(f, t_)}
  {}
  
  R result() const { return result_; }
};
```

---

As a final note, I'm not sure why `C` would be useful, given that `std::apply` exists.

Comment: I could've sworn that I wrote "Below is a simplified implementation"... Admittedly I should've re-read the code after removing most of it but still... This is a snippet of an inner (not explicitly templated) group holder of a range view class so I'm quite sure that it would be useful but thanks for the remarks and concern.